# redux-saga: tracking multiple async tasks

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

I am using sagas to track multiple async tasks, but there is one problem I haven't been able to completely solve:

```
function* performTask1() {
    // Some logic here to takeLatest for the relevant component

    // check if component id matches?

    // Only perform API call with the latest
    const { result } = yield takeLatest('doAsync2')
}

function* performTask2() {
    const { result } = yield call(api, args)
    // do something with results (not relevant)
}

function* watchAsyncTasks() {
    yield takeEvery('doAsync2', performTask2)
    yield takeEvery('doAsync1', performTask1)
}
```

1. componentA dispatches doAsync1
2. componentB dispatches doAsync1
3. component C dispatches doAsync2 (for good measure)
4. componentA dispatches doAsync1
5. componentB dispatches doAsync1

How can I use sagas to ensure that only sagas 3, 4, and 5 complete their API call?

Comment: What you mean by `complete their API call`? you can check this with dispatch success action from those `sagas` right

Comment: To complete an api call means to arrive back from server with data. The problem that I did not make clear enough is that we don't want the results from action 1 arriving before that of action 4 (which we can't guarantee just because 1 fires before 4).

We either want to process 1 and 4 in order OR ensure that we only take the results of 4

Comment: maybe just use takeLatest instead of takeEvery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function* generator(){
    yield call(api,params);
    yield call(api2, params2);
}

const gen = generator;

gen.next() // done: false/true
gen.next() // done: false/true
```

Comment: It's answer, maybe :) My question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215425/redux-saga-watcher-not-working-correctly-what-can-be-a-problem

Comment: Oh sorry I've seen triage and I thought that it is question.